# How to create a DXL attribute using a #included file

Tags: ibm-doors

I have a file containing attribute dxl. I have created a template that creates a module exactly the way I want it, with new attributes and views and such. One of the attributes needs to be a dxl attribute,but I cannot find a good way to create a new dxl attribute from a dxl script using code contained in a separate file. I thought I might try something like this:

String s = #include "filepath"

But that obviously doesn't work. Is there a way to get the contents of a separate file into a string?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using a Stream.

```
Stream inFile = read "filepath"
String s, sContent = ""

while(true) {
  inFile >> s
  sContent = sContent "\n" s
  if(end of inFile) break
}
close inFile
```

This will fill the string `sContent` with your DXL file contents. Then you can use it to create the attribute.

---

Updated Code based on feedback.

Comment: I would point out though that the way you have your while loop setup, your be cutting off the last line of your code every time.

Comment: Actually the last line is the `end` of the file so you wouldn't use it as a line of data. This is how it is structured in the example in the DXL Reference Manual.

Comment: This may be how the DXL manual was written, but it is not how the code you posted actually functions. I used the exact code you posted and it cut off the last line until I moved line 7 to the end of the loop.